# authentication username and password in soapheader

Tags: java, wcf, web-services, authentication, soap

I need to incorporate an authentication header (i.e. as a part of SOAP header request) in my web service. That authentication header will verify the username and password details. I have to verify the content of request header details for authentication in my Web Service. If authenticated, then the SOAP body of the request will be processed, else Invalid Authentication message will be send back by the Web Service to the client application invoking the service.

I am not able to understand how to create a web service where the SOAP Header will contain some elements (in my case, authentication elements such as username and password).

I have a code in .net for authentication like this

```
package org.tele.javabean.Sevicesupportbeans;

import javax.xml.soap.SOAPElement;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPException;

import org.apache.axis.message.SOAPHeaderElement;

public class ManageSoapHeaders {

    public SOAPHeaderElement getAuthenticatesoapHeader(String strUserName,String strPwd)
    {
        SOAPHeaderElement header = new SOAPHeaderElement("http://tempuri.org/", "AuthSoapHd");  
        SOAPElement node;
        SOAPElement node2;
        try {
            node = header.addChildElement("strUserName");
            node.addTextNode(strUserName);  
            node2 = header.addChildElement("strPassword");  
            node2.addTextNode(strPwd); 
        } catch (SOAPException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return header;
    }
}
```

Just I want to change this .NET code into Java code.

Please help.

Regards,

Comment: "I want to change this .NET code into Java code." - What you posted **IS** Java.  That is not .NET.  Is your web service written in Java and you're trying to create a .NET client, or is you service .NET WCF and you're trying to create a Java client?